# How to grouping some character in atom in vimscript?

Tags: vim

Here I want to minify my code:

```
let s:next_col = getline('.')[col('.') - 1]

if s:next_col is# "'" || s:next_col is# '"' || s:next_col is# '`' || ')' || s:next_col is# ']' || s:next_col is# '}' || s:next_col is# '>'
    return "\<right>"
endif
```

The above code work as expected. But when I try convert it to this:

```
let s:next_col = getline('.')[col('.') - 1]

" I also try to add / before \V, not sure if its correct but that also won't work
if s:next_col is# '\V\("\|`\|)\|]\|}\|>\)' || s:next_col is# "'"
    return "\<right>"
endif
```

Now, the only it work will be if the next column is `'`.

I wonder how I can grouping these character `' " ) ] } >` and check if one of those matching with my variable?

Answer (score 0):

`is` and its variants are only useful for comparing lists or dictionaries. If you want to compare strings, then the right operators would be `==`, `!=`, `=~`, `!~` and their case variants.

Here, you can simply use `=~` to compare with a regular expression pattern and, since punctuation marks don't have casing, there is no need for `#` or `?`:

```
let s:next_col = getline('.')[col('.') - 1]
if s:next_col =~ "['\"`)\\]}>]"
    return "\<right>"
endif
```

- `[...]` is a collection. See `:help /[]`.
- `'`, `` ` ``, `)`, `}`, and `>` are all used as-is because they have no special meaning in Vim's regex dialect.
- `"` is escaped with a `\` because double quotes are used for quoting the pattern.
- `]` is escaped once because `]` closes the collection, which makes it special in Vim's regex dialect, and a second time because `\` is special in double quotes. See `:help expr-"`.

Comment: Instead of trying random things, you need to learn how regular expressions work, which is totally beyond the scope of this site. See [vimregex.com](http://vimregex.com/) for a gentle introduction to Vim's regex dialect.